# How to retrieve non-selected rows from a Jtable and store in an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I have randomly displayed data to JTable from a mysql database.
Below is the query used for generating random records of size 10

```
select *from tableName order by rand() limit 0,10;
```

I am able to display records in a JTable. However, I want to retrieve **non-selected** as well as **selected** rows from a Jtable and store in two separate  ArrayList(or any collection).

Comment: If by 'select' you mean the DB, this has nothing to do with Swing. OTOH if by 'select' you mean the user selecting rows in the `JTable`, this has nothing to do with the DB. Which is it? The one thing that's clear is that this has nothing to do with the IDE being used, so don't add that tag.

Comment: I meant the user selects rows in the Jtable. However, I have used the query mentioned as part of the question to randomly generate 10 rows from the mysql database.

Comment: *"I meant the user selects rows in the Jtable." For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code some data to replace the DB.